# VC++ belongs to Managed or unmanaged category?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, clr

After reading some stuffs about the managed and unmanaged code,i realized that in managed compiler generates IL, which any machine can understand.  All we need to do is just deploy the assembly in any other machine and CLR helps to run it right.

But, also i read that VC++ does not support CLR and its unmanaged code. But we can run VC++ binary in any machine without any modification. It need not be having same configuration as the machine which we build exe.

Please clarify what exactly unmanaged and managed code is?, if Unmanaged code should not run in any other machine having little different config like different mother board, chipset etc... How VC++ binary runs over there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot run VC++ binary on any machine without any modification. You can only run it on a Windows machine, and even that - not any. Current VC++ 64 bit executables will not run under older Win 95, for example.

Managed code is code converted to the IL, that is interpreted by the CLR at run time. Non-managed code is code converted to *native* machine code, which is run directly by the CPU.

Comment: To run .net exe, we require .net framework to run on some other machine. Its not the case for VC++ MFC exe right?

Comment: @LLL yes, but "other machine" != "other platform". You cannot run windows EXE on a UNIX machine (not without emulator, at least), for example. You don't need to have the same configuration, but you do need to have the same platform (i.e.: same OS and architecture).

Comment: can we run .net exe in unix?, if so how it works?, CLR will be installed in unix by default?,

Comment: @LLL you need something installed for nearly all cases. For programs written with Visual C++, you normally need the VC++ Runtime. If you use MFC, you need the mfc dlls as well. If you compile for .net (using C++/CLI as language), you need the .net runtime. This all works only on Windows OS - except for some .NET programs (using again C++/CLI) that can run with mono on all platforms supporting this.

Comment: @LLL CLR is not installed by default on unix. You need mono installed for that and you have to make sure to compile your code with the /clr:pure compiler switch for CLR. You are then however restricted in what you are allowed to do with C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Normally VC++ generates unmanaged binaries. They can be run on all windows computers (possibly with the c++-redist package).

To created a managed (.NET) application with c++ you need to use [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI).

Managed code in this case is .NET and unmanaged code is native binaries.

To run unmanaged binaries you need the dependent libraries on the machine, to run managed code you need the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ is **not a language** it is a IDE from microsoft which comes with a compiler and a set of libraries. You can use this compiler to generate either managed or unmanaged code. In case of unmanaged code it will generate an exe (or dll or some other binary) whose format Windows understands. OS (Windows in this case) abstracts all other details such as processor, mother board etc from you.

Comment: actually - Visual Studio is the IDE, Visual C++ is the compiler & runtime, C++ is the language.